# What is the difference in ASP.NET startup between a recycle and a recompile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, startup

When my MVC app is first deployed it works fine, up until the point when the application pool is recycled. After that, none of the routes work and I receive 404s for everything. Forcing a rebuild by editing the web.config or redeploying will bring the site back online, until the next recycle.

My MVC setup is a bit atypical. I'm doing quite a lot on startup, such as scanning assemblies for routes that need to be loaded. I feel like there must be some Global.asax event that only fires on the initial build but is not run on a recycle.

What are the differences between the recycle and the rebuild in terms of startup events?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is apparently nothing. My problems stemmed from a garbage collection issue where resources weren't being cleaned up.